# PHPMyadmin doesn't seem to be able to read zip files compressed with 7zip

Tags: zip, 7-zip, phpmyadmin

Each time I get this when trying to import:

> Error in ZIP archive: CRC32 checksum
>   is not equal with the value in header
>   information.

Which software should I use for phpmyadmin then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of PHPMyAdmin are you using?

I see [bug #2808564](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=377408&aid=2808564&group_id=23067) which sounds quite similar to your issue.  The filer indicates that only certain files caused the issue.  It was recommended to upgrade to PHPMyAdmin v3.2.

If you can't upgrade PHPMyAdmin, you could try using another archiver to create the zip, such as WinZip or WinRar.  You could also try using another compression format such as Gzip.

Comment: phpMyAdmin 2.11.9.4 I can't change as it is dreamhost so thanks for suggestion will try with other zippers